# I deleted the Python25 folder from my computer and reinstalling python doesn't fix the problem

Tags: python

I had a problem where the python version in the folder C:/csvn/Python25 which was 2.7.1, kept overwriting the install of Python 3.10.2. So I thought it would be a smart idea to completely wipe it from my pc.

I have tried rebooting the system, reinstalling python, but nothing seems to help. What do I do?

The error I get:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9YGa.png]

edit*

1. I have now identified the problem and have fixed it by simply downloading python from the Microsoft marketplace (yes, i am very ashamed), but seems to have fixed the problem.
2. I also believe the problem lies in how the system prioritizes different versions of python installed on the system. So if anyone has a problem with conflicting versions they should macbe try reinstalling python from the marketplace.

Comment: What are you trying to run?

Comment: Have you tried correcting the environment variable PYTHONHOME for the account and or system to the path of the installation you want to use? Search for environment in windows search. Open a new command prompt after changes.

Comment: That's not an error message, that's a screenshot.

Comment: You should try editing system environment variables. Delete the ones linkes python2.5.

Comment: This is actually not a programming question but one concerning system administration. E.g. superuser.com would be a better place to ask. That said, Python 3 has been released more than ten years ago, so please forget about 2.5 and update!

Answer (score 0):

1. I have now identified the problem and have fixed it by simply downloading python from the Microsoft marketplace (yes, i am very ashamed), but seems to have fixed the problem.
2. I also believe the problem lies in how the system prioritizes different versions of python installed on the system. So if anyone has a problem with conflicting versions they should macbe try reinstalling python from the marketplace.